# Can I permanently delete project data on Asana?

Tags: asana

I support a legal, security-conscious team migrating to Asana. One of the team members asked me to verify that we can permanently delete project data when we need to, so that it disappears forever and can't be subpeona'd. Asana appears to archive but not delete project data (I see task data can be permanently deleted).

Hence my question, is there a way to permanently delete project data? If not, I will have to abandon our migration.

Here is Asana's manual page about it, talking about "undo links":
https://asana.com/guide/help/projects/archive#gl-delete

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a legal question rather than a technical one (though I can say that undo links expire after 7 days, on a technical level).

I'd recommend reaching out to support, and note that this question may not be appropriate for StackOverflow (which focuses on coding rather than legal compliance issues, as far as I know)